# Display clicked image on react carousel

Tags: reactjs, carousel, fullscreen

I have multiple images in my project.
What I want to do is to display the current clicked image on a image carousel in fullscreen. I am using Bootstrap Model to get the image to fullscreen

Now when I click on the image, the image that is first in the array shows. I want the current clicked image to show, and the carousel can start from there (and go back and forward to the first and last image in the array).

Here is my code

Media.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import MediaFullscreen from "./MediaFullscreen";

export function Media() {
  const [files, setFile] = useState([]);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3001/media")
      .then((res) => {
        setFile(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  const setimgfile = (e) => {
    setFile(e.target.files);
  };

  const addUserData = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData();

    for (const file of files) {
      formData.append("files", file);
    }

    const res = axios
      .post("http://localhost:3001/media", formData)
      .then((window.location.href = "/media"));

    if (res.data.status === 201) {
      console.log("NO error");
    } else {
      console.log("error");
    }
  };

  const fileList = files ? [...files] : [];

  const closeModal = () => setShowModal(false);
  const openModal = () => setShowModal(true);

  return showModal ? (
    <MediaFullscreen
      openModal={openModal}
      closeModal={closeModal}
      fileList={fileList}
    />
  ) : (
    <div style={{ padding: 15, backgroundColor: "#fff", marginTop: 15 }}>
      <h4>Upload file:</h4>
      <input type="file" name="photo" onChange={setimgfile} multiple />
      <button type="submit" onClick={addUserData}>
        submit
      </button>
      <ul>
        {fileList.map((file, i) => (
          <li key={i}>
            <img
              src={"http://localhost:3001/images/" + file.image}
              onClick={showModal()}
              alt={file.image}
              id={file.id}
            />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Media;
```

MediaFullscreen.js

- Not sure is "react-multi-carousel" is the best package to use though.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Modal, Image } from "react-bootstrap";
import Carousel from "react-multi-carousel";

function MediaFullscreen({ openModal, closeModal, fileList }) {
  const responsive = {
    desktop: {
      breakpoint: {
        max: 3000,
        min: 1024,
      },
      items: 1,
    },
    mobile: {
      breakpoint: {
        max: 464,
        min: 0,
      },
      items: 1,
    },
    tablet: {
      breakpoint: {
        max: 1024,
        min: 464,
      },
      items: 1,
    },
  };

  return (
    <Modal show={openModal} onHide={closeModal} variant="dark">
      <Modal.Header closeButton />
      <Modal.Body>
        <Carousel
          arrows
          autoPlaySpeed={3000}
          centerMode={false}
          className=""
          containerClass="container"
          responsive={responsive}
          shouldResetAutoplay
          showDots
          sliderClass=""
          slidesToSlide={1}
        >
          {fileList.map((d, index) => (
            <img
              key={index}
              variant="top"
              src={"http://localhost:3001/images/" + d.image}
              style={{
                display: "block",
                height: "100%",
                margin: "auto",
                width: "100%",
              }}
            />
          ))}
        </Carousel>
      </Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
  );
}

export default MediaFullscreen;
```

Thanks in advance, and appreciate any help :)